# "Requires" entry in .spec file does not work

Tags: packaging, rpm

I was writing an .spec file for a rpm package and I'm having an issue.
I need to install that package with a specific version of another package.
Let's take a python package example. So, I write it:

```
Requires        : bash, grep, python >= 2.6.7-4b
```

But, the package is installed even if the python package is in the 2.6.6 version.
If I remove python package, the system shows me that my package needs python 2.6.7.

Is there something wrong?

Output from `rpm -q --provides python`:

```
Distutils
python(abi) = 2.6
python-abi = 2.6
python-ctypes = 1.0.1
python-hashlib = 20081120
python-sqlite = 2.3.2
python-uuid = 1.31
python-x86_64 = 2.6.6-52.el6
python2 = 2.6.6
python = 2.6.6-52.el6
python(x86-64) = 2.6.6-52.el6
```

Output from `rpm -qpR $yourpackage.rpm`:

```
/bin/sh
python >= 2.6.7-4b
bash
grep
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PartialHardlinkSets) <= 4.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

Comment: Can you post the output for `rpm -q --provides python` on the system where 2.6.6 is installed and satisfies your packages requirement? Also post the `rpm -qR $yourpackage` or `rpm -qpR $yourpackage.rpm` output please.

Comment: @EtanReisner the output of the first command is:
Distutils  
python(abi) = 2.6
python-abi = 2.6
python-ctypes = 1.0.1
python-hashlib = 20081120
python-sqlite = 2.3.2
python-uuid = 1.31
python-x86_64 = 2.6.6-52.el6
python2 = 2.6.6
python = 2.6.6-52.el6
python(x86-64) = 2.6.6-52.el6

and the output of the last command is:
/bin/sh
python >= 2.6.7-4b
bash
grep
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PartialHardlinkSets) <= 4.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1

Comment: I did a quick test on my CentOS 5 machine where the installed version of python is `2.4.3-56` (with a dummy package that requires `python >= 2.4.4-15`) and rpm failed to install the package correctly. Are you sure the system has the python package you are expecting? What does 'rpm -q --whatprovides python` say on the system?

Comment: @EtanReisner When I put `python(x86-64) >= 2.6.7-4b` it works. =) But How can I define a generic way to identify what architecture I'm using. For example, if my machine is i386 it needs to require python(x86-32) and if I'm using x86_64 it needs to require python(x86-64).

Comment: Is there really a `python(x86-32)` provide on 32bit systems? That would surprise me. You can use `%_arch` for the current architecture in the spec file and do detection/etc. based on that if you need to but I don't know why changing `python >= ...` to `python(x86-64) >= ...` should make a difference here.

Comment: Let remember you, Etan, that I'm using python as an example. =) Here I have many packages of my projects with that Pre-requires problems. I don't know why it's making the diference. But it works. It's really strange.

Comment: But you've actually run into the problem with your test using python? You aren't showing an example that you haven't tested for the actual problem, right? Because if you can't reproduce it with python (as written) then other things might be going on.

Answer (score 3):

The ''Requires:'' tag is ignored unless you add ''Autoreq: no'' as well.

Newer versions of rpmbuild calculate the requirements automatically and ignore ''Requires:'' unless the feature is turned off.

I have run into this issue multiple times and it is worth noting that you should at first run rpmbuild **without** ''Autoreq: no'', note the autodetected dependencies, and add them to the ''Required:'' tag before the final run with ''Autoreq: no''.

Is also worth noting that the automatic detection of dependencies is a little buggy and has some issues with comments.
I packaged a perl script with a comment containing " ... then use a module ... " a while ago.
Autoreq detected that as being perl module "perl a" and added it to the dependencies making my rpm useless.